# How to get value of the HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a question, how can i get value of the element using javaScript with Jquery? I have tried this and error sad .val() is not a function and i could not find any solution. Everithink i found told me it is not a function. Thanks for reply.

```js
const btn = $('.btn');
let example = $('#example');
let result = $('#result');
var test = btn.value;


btn.on('click', function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
})
```

```css
.btn{
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 3vh;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 4%;
    width: 20%;
    height: 12vh;
    background: red;
    line-height:12vh;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:300%;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
            <div class="btn" val="1">1</div>

**
```

**

Comment: From the [documentation for `.val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/)... _"The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as `input`, `select` and `textarea`"_. If you want the `val` attribute value of your `<div>`, use `$(this).attr("val")`. If you want the text content, use `$(this).text()`

Comment: Only `input` elements have `value` property. What you actually mean is called `custom attribute`, but it should probably start with that word `data-` to comply the the spec (but it's not a must)

Comment: Use `var title = $( ".btn" ).attr( "val" );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `$(this).attr` for this

`val()` works only on input or buttons

```js
const btn = $('.btn');
let example = $('#example');
let result = $('#result');
var test = btn.value;


btn.on('click', function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('val'));
   
})
```

```css
.btn{
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 3vh;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 4%;
    width: 20%;
    height: 12vh;
    background: red;
    line-height:12vh;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:300%;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn" val="1">1</div>

**
```